# Kendo ui for angular: bind click event of kendoButton to a method of a variable in the component

Tags: angular, events, button, kendo-ui-angular2, event-binding

I have a component-variable "message" of type "any" that holds a method "actionnowrapper()"

Whenever I bind to a button like below, this works well.

```cs
<button (click)="message.actionnowrapper()"></button>
```

Whenever I use the kendoButton directive, this no longer works.

```cs
<button kendoButton (click)="message.actionnowrapper()"></button>
```

Binding the Kendobutton directly to a method in the component does the trick, but this is not what we need.

```cs
 <button (click)="actionnowrapper()"></button>
```

How can I bind a kendobutton to a method in a component-variable?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular button and Kendo button click handlers work in the same way:

```
<button kendoButton (click)="message.actionnowrapper('kendo')">Click</button>
<button (click)="message.actionnowrapper('regular')">Click</button>

export class AppComponent {
message = {
  actionnowrapper: (buttonType: string) => {
      alert(`${buttonType} button clicked`)
    } 
  }
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/yJg6W2hDXTwmiJ1imYfb?p=preview)

Comment: I have a different issue.  I can't get the properties of a Kendo Button imported in the .ts file to be assignable in the <button> tags in the .html template file.  In React, this works but I'm using Angular. I can't code in a default function, like in React, with the HTML using the Button type within the .ts file.

There has to be a way for something like <button [svgIcon] = folderIcon> to be set. but this errors out as unassignable.

Comment: The button should be marked as an actual Kendo Button component applying the `kendoButton` selector or using `kendo-button` instead of `button` tag (ButtonsModule should be imported):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mlrdcz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Otherwise, Angular cannot recognize the custom input properties like `svgIcon` on a regular button element (as such do not exist, the Kendo Button component provides them).